# When top is not set, why a position: absolute div is not overlapped with its siblings

Tags: css, css-position

Context: When the `position:absolute` `<div>` is directly in `<body>`, and there is a `<div>` as a sibling of it as in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re4fnLzh/).

Question: Why the `position:absolute` `<div>`does not overlap with its siblings when the `top` property is not explicitly set.

To my understanding but may be incorrect, if a `<div>` is set to be `position:absolute`, it will be positioned relative to body if none of its parents and parents' parents is set to be `position:relative`. So the `top`
 propery of the `position:absolute` `<div>` should default to the `body` origin and the two `div`s should overlap.

The code is here:

```css
#box_1 { 
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

#box_2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="box_1"></div>
      <div id="box_2"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: If you have code that is relevant to your question then include that code directly in your question; do not link to a remote website where you have hosted that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

It is because the default `top` value is `auto` so it lets the browser calculate the top edge position.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top#Values):

> For absolutely positioned elements, the position of the element is
>   based on the `bottom` property, while `height: auto` is treated as a
>   height based on the content; or if `bottom` is also `auto`, the
>   element is positioned where it should vertically be positioned if it
>   were a static element.

So it will be positioned according to the `bottom` or the `top`, but as there is none in your example, **it is positioned as a static element**.

---

**Old answer:**

Because you set `bottom: 0;` so it sticks the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, I posted a wrong JSFiddler just now. I simply add the HTML and CSS to the question. Could you please take a look again?

Comment: Cool thank you so much. MDN has a better explanation then W3CSchool.